# Unary minus messes up parsing

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Here is the grammar of the language id' like to parse:

```
expr ::= val | const | (expr) | unop expr | expr binop expr
var ::= letter
const ::= {digit}+
unop ::= -
binop ::= /*+-
```

I'm using an example from the [haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/index.php?title=Parsing_expressions_and_statements).

The semantics and token parser are not shown here.

```
exprparser = buildExpressionParser table term <?> "expression"

table = [ [Prefix (m_reservedOp "-" >> return (Uno Oppo))] 
         ,[Infix (m_reservedOp "/"  >> return (Bino Quot)) AssocLeft
          ,Infix (m_reservedOp "*"  >> return (Bino Prod)) AssocLeft]
         ,[Infix (m_reservedOp "-"  >> return (Bino Diff)) AssocLeft
          ,Infix (m_reservedOp "+"  >> return (Bino Somm)) AssocLeft]
        ]

term = m_parens exprparser
       <|> fmap Var m_identifier
       <|> fmap Con m_natural
```

The minus char appears two times, once as unary, once as binary operator.

On input `"1--2"`, the parser gives only
`Con 1`

instead of the expected
`"Bino Diff (Con 1) (Uno Oppo (Con 2))"`

Any help welcome.[Full code here](https://framabin.org/p/?14d59e926693d25d#TIsneb0Y1TKNkOMNJQ/31H5Ba60VMjgGlEpgZVxP7e8=)

Comment: You appear to be using the Haskell tokenizer, which removes `--2` as a comment before parsing begins.

Comment: I think not:see this other issue: ```" -1+-2*3"``` gives ```"Uno Oppo (Con 1)"```

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `reservedOp` is to create a parser (which you've named `m_reservedOp`) that parses the given string of operator symbols while ensuring that it is **not** the prefix of a longer string of operator symbols.  You can see this from the definition of `reservedOp` in the source:

```
reservedOp name =
    lexeme $ try $
    do{ _ <- string name
      ; notFollowedBy (opLetter languageDef) <?> ("end of " ++ show name)
      }
```

Note that the supplied `name` is parsed only if it is not followed by any `opLetter` symbols.

In your case, the string `"--2"` can't be parsed by `m_reservedOp "-"` because, even though it starts with the valid operator `"-"`, this string occurs as the prefix of a longer valid operator `"--"`.

In a language with single-character operators, you probably don't want to use `reservedOp` at all, unless you want to disallow adjacent operators without intervening whitespace.  Just use `symbol "-"`, which will always parse `"-"`, no matter what follows (and consume following whitespace, if any).  Also, in a language with a *fixed set* of operators (i.e., no user-defined operators), you probably won't use the `operator` parser, so you won't need `opStart`, or `reservedOpNames`.  Without `reservedOp` or `operator`, the `opLetter` parser isn't used, so you can drop it too.

This is probably pretty confusing, and the `Parsec` documentation does a terrible job of explaining how the "reserved" mechanism is supposed to work.  Here's a primer:

Let's start with identifiers, instead of operators.  In a typical language that allows user-defined identifiers (i.e., pretty much any language, since "variables" and "functions" have user-defined names) and may also have some reserved words that aren't allowed as identifiers, the relevant settings in the `GenLanguageDef` are:

```
identStart       -- parser for first character of valid identifier
identLetter      -- second and following characters of valid identifier
reservedNames    -- list of reserved names not allowed as identifiers
```

The lexeme (whitespace-absorbing) parsers created using the `GenTokenParser` object are:

- `identifier` - Parses an unknown, user-defined identifier.  It parses a character from `identStart` followed by zero or more `identLetter`s up to the first non-`identLetter`.  (It never parses a partial identifier, so it'll never leave more `identLetter`s on the table.)  **Additionally,** it checks that the identifier is not in the list `reservedNames`.
- `symbol` - Parses the given string.  If the string is a reserved word, no check is made that it isn't part of a larger valid identifier.  So, `symbol "for"` would match the beginning of `foreground = "black"`, which is rarely what you want.  Note that `symbol` makes no use of `identStart`, `identLetter`, or `reservedNames`.
- `reserved` - Parses the given string, and then ensures that it's not followed by an `identLetter`.  So, `m_reserved "for"` will parse `for (i=1; ...` but *not* parse `foreground = "black"`.  Usually, the supplied string will be a valid identifier, but no check is made for this, so you can write `m_reserved "15"` if you want -- in a language with the usual sorts of alphanumeric identifiers, this would parse `"15"` provided it wasn't following by a letter or another digit.  Also, maybe somewhat surprisingly, no check is made that the supplied string is in `reservedNames`.

If that makes sense to you, then the operator settings follow the exact same pattern.  The relevant settings are:

```
opStart          -- parser for first character of valid operator
opLetter         -- valid second and following operator chars, for multichar operators
reservedOpNames  -- list of reserved operator names not allowed as user-defined operators
```

and the relevant parsers are:

- `operator` - Parses an unknown, user-defined operator starting with an `opStart` and followed by zero or more `opLetter`s up to the first non-`opLetter`.  So, `operator` applied to the string `"--2"` will always take the whole operator `"--"`, never just the prefix `"-"`.  An additional check is made that the resulting operator is not in the `reservedOpNames` list.
- `symbol` - Exactly as for identifiers.  It parses a string with no checks or reference to `opStart`, `opLetter`, or `reservedOpNames`, so `symbol "-"` will parse the first character of the string `"--"` just fine, leaving the second `"-"` character for a later parser.
- `reservedOp` - Parses the given string, ensuring it's not followed by `opLetter`.  So, `m_reservedOp "-"` will parse the start of `"-x"` but not `"--2"`, assuming `-` matches `opLetter`.  As before, no check is made that the string is in `reservedOpNames`.